# How do I fix the camera in animation mode?

Tags: animation, camera

I went into animation mode, and as usual, the panel on the side where it shows what the camera sees is there, but later, it is no longer showing the camera's view. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click and drag move the mouse cursor, it goes off the camera view mode. You can fix it by repressing the button:

[image]

If you're trying to move the actual camera while viewing it(without it losing view[Viewing it live]), adjust the camera transformation here:

[image]